# In c# windows desktop how to form make responsive according to PC Size fit

Tags: c#, windows, desktop

I have created windows desktop application and having one form according to my PC size but another PC Resolution is low so form it's not showing properly so how to form make responsive according to PC Size fit.
All control fit according its.

Is there any properties or other ways?
I tried the below code but it's not getting solutions perfectly

`this.Size=Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size; this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; this.Width=SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Width; this.Height = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height;`

Comment: Use anchors in the designer

Comment: Maximize only handle the form itself, not the controls inside. This is partly why WPF is a thing since it can be painful to have WinForm controls adjusting to the size change.

Answer (score 2):

### [Anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

When you set anchors for a control, you specify which edges of the control should maintain a fixed distance from the corresponding edges of its parent container (e.g., a Form). There are four anchor points: top, bottom, left, and right.

- To make a control resize horizontally with the parent, set both left and right anchors. For vertical resizing, set both top and bottom anchors.
- If you set all four anchors, the control will resize proportionally with the parent, maintaining its distance from all four edges.

[image: Resizing using Anchors]

### [Dock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

The Dock property allows a control to automatically assume a position within its parent container and resize accordingly. When you dock a control, it will fill the entire available space in the specified direction (Top, Bottom, Left, Right, or Fill).

- Docking is particularly useful when you want controls to occupy specific regions within a container, such as a toolbar at the top, a status bar at the bottom, and a central content area in the middle.
- Keep in mind that controls with the Dock property take precedence over Anchor and Location settings, so those properties are ignored.

### Layout Panels

To simplify control arrangement and resizing, consider using layout panels like `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel`. These panels automatically manage the positioning and sizing of controls within them, making it easier to create dynamic layouts.

### Further Resources

For in-depth information and examples on Anchors and Docking, refer to the official Microsoft documentation on [how to dock and anchor controls in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-dock-and-anchor?view=netdesktop-7.0).

Experimenting with these techniques will give you a solid understanding of how to create flexible and responsive layouts for your Windows Forms applications.

BTW: The WinForms seem to be more or less obsolete, It may be better to put effort in another framework like WPF.